# Getting multiple namespaces when trying to set one

Tags: python, lxml, python-pptx

I'm trying to set a namespace in a PowerPoint chart XML file, but doing so gives me two namespaces. The documentation and resources I've found led me to believe setting the namespace like an attribute would be best.

This function:

```
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, QName

def function(graphic_frame):
    chart = graphic_frame.chart
    chart_xml = chart._element

    NS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart'
    bracket_NS = "{" + NS + "}c16r2"
    etree.register_namespace('c16r2', NS)
    chart_xml.set(bracket_NS, NS)
```

Gives this result:

```
<c:chartSpace 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" 
xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:c16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart" 
c16r2:c16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart">
```

The "c16r2:c16r2" is unwanted.

I feel as though I'm missing something obvious. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the namespace? It's not going to show up in every element just because it's registered. It will only appear when an element or attribute *requires* (uses) it.

If you add an element or attribute that *uses* that namespace (once it's registered), its namespace-prefix mapping will appear in the XML you print out. That's effectively what you've done, just in a way that is confusing.

Let's register the `c16r2` namespace prefix and then use it to add a `c16r2:foo` attribute:

```
>>> chart_element = chart._element
>>> chart_element.xml
<c:chartSpace 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart"
...

>>> NS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart'
>>> etree.register_namespace('c16r2', NS)
>>> chart_element.xml
<c:chartSpace 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart"
...  # --- no change ---

>>> foo_attr_clark_name = "{%s}%s" % (NS, "foo")
>>> chart_element.set(foo_attr_clark_name, "bar")
>>> chart_element.xml
<c:chartSpace 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart"
...
# --- registered namespace appears ---
xmlns:c16r2=http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart
# --- because you've added element-or-attribute that needs it ---
c16r2:foo="bar">
```

Comment: I'm attempting to create Combo charts (one bar, one line), and I'm getting errors when opening PPT. I'm not sure what PPT objects to in my current approach, as I believe I've replicated the major structure, so I'm trying to replicate the XML of one I created manually. I obviously don't fully understand this yet, so I appreciate the background.